# Sum of series $\frac85+\frac{16}{65}+\cdots \cdots +\cdots +\frac{128}{2^{18}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

sum of series $\displaystyle \frac{8}{5}+\frac{16}{65}+\cdots \cdots  +\frac{128}{2^{18}+1}$

I have calculate $\displaystyle a_{n} = \frac{2^{n+2}}{4^{2n-1}+1}$

could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: these are very few terms, you can easily sum them using a simple calculator.

Comment: Hint: $2^{5+2}=128$.

Comment: I think he means $\sum_k a_k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write $\displaystyle a_{n} = \frac{2^{n+2}}{4^{2n-1}+1} $ as $\displaystyle T_{n} = \frac{16.2^{n}}{2^{4n}+4} $

$\displaystyle T_{n} = \frac{4}{2^{2n}-2.2^{n}+2}-\frac{4}{2^{2n}+2.2^{n}+2} $

Adding upto n terms we get
$\displaystyle S_{n} = 2-\frac{4}{2^{2n}+2.2^{n}+2} $ as it is telescopic

Solving n=5

$\displaystyle S_{5} = 2-\frac{4}{1090}=\frac{1088}{545} $

Comment: @DXT  The answer is correct, if you are satisfied with it, please close this problem